# How to call wait() based on a condition with ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, threadpoolexecutor

In my case, I run a for loop which calls execute.submit(my_function). Because of a nature of the ThreadPoolExecutor tasks run asynchronously.

My function isn't something like collecting some values and then doing a job. On the contrary the job runs as soon as it triggered and calls some API and do some stuff. I need to send a flag value to close the API session. So, this is why the latest job(based on a counter) of the loop needs to run as the final job of the pool.

How can I achieve this with a conditional way by using the wait() module and passing a parameter to my function?

Here is a simplified code I have tackled till now:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import threading

def my_function()
   #do something

def poolexecutor_for_my_task():
   with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for _ in range(0, 10):
             executor.submit(my_function)

poolexecutor_for_my_task()
```

Here is the one what I want to do(hypothetically):

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import threading

def my_function()
   #do something

def poolexecutor_for_my_task():
   last_batch_flag = 'False'
   with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for _ in range(0, 10):
            executor.submit(my_function)  #call the function which can run asynchronously
            #do something which may change the flag as True in some point
            if last_batch_flag == 'True'
                 executor.submit(my_function,last_completed)  #this needs to be run as the final job
            
poolexecutor_for_my_task()
```

Is this possible with a similar logic?

Comment: It’s unclear what you’re asking. Do you want to break out of the loop after starting the last job? Then just use `break`. Or do you not want that job to start until all the other jobs have finished? Use `pool.join()`.

Comment: The problem here is that "last" has no meaning in this case.  No one is promising that these threads will execute and/or complete in order.  If you have stuff that needs to be done after all the threads are finished, then you need to wait for them all to complete, which means after the `with` finishes.

Comment: @FrankYellin, I edited the post and the title to make it more clear. Basically what I want is to call execute.submit(my_function) and let all the jobs run asynchronously except the one which is to be sent in the condition. Hope is clear now.

Comment: This flag value is a parameter to `my_function`? Or maybe a different function? Do you want this last thing to execute in the background while you do other stuff? Or, maybe just call `my_function(the_final_flag)` in the main thread?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
def my_function(last=False)
   #do something

def poolexecutor_for_my_task():
   last_batch_flag = False
   with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for _ in range(10):
            executor.submit(my_function,last_batch_flag)
```

However, there are problems here.  The `for` loop is going to run basically instantly.  Thanks to the GIL, you will have finished submitting all 10 threads before anything else can set the flag.

Is parallelism really appropriate here?  Would these be better as serial tasks?

Perhaps a better design would be:

```
def my_function(last=False)
   #do something

def poolexecutor_for_my_task():
   with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for _ in range(10):
            executor.submit(my_function)
   my_function(True)
```

Comment: This will complicate the whole program. Plus, whole job duration is more than the desired duration if I run as serial tasks. So, parallelism is kind of a must in my case to speed up the things. That is why I'm looking something to run all the jobs asynchronously except the one that I need to send lastly with a condition. Is this concept exist or not?

Comment: Perhaps you didn't understand what I wrote.  I'm executing your tasks in parallel, but then doing the special "clean up" task after they have all completed.